# Use of CASE WHEN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables,

> table1 contains matchid,mdate(matchdate),stadium,team1,team2
>
> table2 contains matchid,teamid,playername, goal time(time at which goal was
>   scored)

Here, team1,team2,teamid are the same (abbrevations for country that's playing like 'GER', 'POL', RUS' etc)

Now I need to list every match with the goals scored by each team in the form of a table3

> table3 will contain matchdate,team1,score1,team2,score2

where score1 is number of goals scored by team1 and score2 is number of goals scored by team2 respectively

I tried using this query but it gives error. Any help will be appreciated

> ```
> SELECT mdate,team1,score1,team2,score2
>
>   CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN count(gtime)=score1 ELSE 0
>
>   CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN count(gtime) ELSE 0 
>   END
> ```

```
  FROM game JOIN goal ON table1.matchid = table2.matchid

  group by matchid
```

EDIT: The qestion is query 13from sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation
Also, I realized the mistake in my case when statement. Thanks all for the help

Comment: And which SQL dialect is this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this statement in your query: count(gtime)=score1

Comment: what do you mean by sql dialect?

Comment: What do you expect with `count(gtime)=score1` ?

Comment: @Parado I expect to sum all the goals scored by the team using that.

Comment: `count(gtime)=score1` this is condition it returns `true` or `false`

Comment: Oh, @Parado then kindly tell me as to how to proceed? I just began wil sql programming and am not so proficient with it. I am not able to find anyother way in which I can find all goals scored by a team in the match and also my case when statement seems terribly wrong

Comment: When you need a CASE WHEN construct in an SQL query, it's likely that you should either reconsider your database schema or move any complex logic to the application which uses the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT game.mdate,
       game.team1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS score1,
       game.team2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS score2
FROM game 
JOIN goal ON goal.matchid = game.id
GROUP BY game.mdate, game.team1, game.team2
```

Makes you think what happens in case of an own-goal though.

Comment: will the own goal thing affect it? the q is q 13from http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

Comment: you took a look at the url? now could you explain further on the own goal data?

Comment: @Naga Since you are sorting on team, own goals should not affect it (I assume these will have the player of other team). That being said: if no goals are scored, the original query I gave should not work. Left join should fix that though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the result in 2 columns, you are missing a comma, otherwise your syntax is wrong. You dont need the second "case" word

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'equal'  when 1=3 THEN 'not equal' END
```

Comment: what will this help me do?

Comment: that's an example of how to write your query

Comment: oh ok, but then how do I use it to get total goals scored by a team in a match here?

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about what you're after due to lack of clarity in question, but perhaps you're wanting something like this:

```
SELECT mdate,team1,score1,team2,score2
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM game 
JOIN goal 
  ON matchid = id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to think about this is by aggregating the `goal` table to get the results for each team independently (for each game).  Then join this back to the `game` table to get the scores you want:

```
SELECT m.mdate, m.team1, g1.score, m.team2, g2.score
FROM game JOIN
     (select matchid, teamid, count(*) as score
      from goal
      group by matchid, teamid
     ) g1
     ON g2.matchid = game.matchid and
        g1.teamid = game.team1 join
     (select matchid, teamid, count(*) as score
      from goal
      group by matchid, teamid
     ) g2
     ON g2.matchid = game.matchid and
        g2.teamid = game.team2;
```